# Create temp table and load data into it using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have three different SQL scripts, and I am able to execute them and get the desired results. I want to put them all into a Temp Table, and use it as a Stored procedure, and get the data displayed on the temp table. Below is the Procedure that I have created.

I want to know how to create a temp table and insert this data into it by executing the SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SurveyTracking]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- AVAILABLE
    SELECT DISTINCT P.Clinic
        , P.LastName
        , P.FirstName
        , SA.SI AS SID
        , ser.SD
        -- , 'Available' as Status
        , ss.SDate 
        , ss.SDtTm
    FROM 
        Table_Name SA
        Inner join Schedule ss on sa.SIID = ss.SIID
        Inner join Patient p on p.PID = ss.PID
        Inner join Clinical.SSJun ssj on ssj.SSJID = ss.SSJID
        Inner join Clinical.SS ser on ser.SSID = ssj.SSID
    WHERE 
        SS.SDtTm IS NOT NULL
        AND (SS.SDtTm < SS.SDate)
        AND (SS.SDate > GETDATE())
        AND SS.Canc = 0
        AND sa.AD = 'Completed'
        AND GETDATE() > ss.SDate
    Order by p.CID;

    --COMPLETED
        SELECT DISTINCT p.Clinic
            , p.LastName
            , p.FirstName
            , ser.SD
            --, 'Completed' as Status
            , ss.SDate
        FROM 
            Table_Name SA
        Inner join Schedule ss on sa.SIID = ss.SIID
        Inner join Patient p on p.PID = ss.PID
        Inner join Clinical.SSJun ssj on ssj.SSJID = ss.SSJID
        Inner join Clinical.SS ser on ser.SSID = ssj.SSID
        WHERE
            sa.AD = 'Completed'  and ss.Cancelled = 0 
        order by p.CID;
    -- OVERDUE
        SELECT  DISTINCT p.CD
              ,p.LastName
              ,p.FirstName
              ,sa.SIID
              ,ser.SD
              ,'Overdue' as Status
              ,ss.SDate
              ,GetDate() as CurrentDate
        FROM 
            Table_Name SA
        Inner join Schedule ss on sa.SIID = ss.SIID
        Inner join Patient p on p.PID = ss.PID
        Inner join Clinical.SSJun ssj on ssj.SSJID = ss.SSJID
        Inner join Clinical.SS ser on ser.SSID = ssj.SSID
        WHERE
            GetDate() > ss.SDate  and ss.Cancelled = 0 
            order by p.CID;
END
```

Comment: You shouldn't use sp_ prefix in your procedures. It has a special purpose and is supposed to be used only by the system procedures

Comment: Do you want this in a single temp table? You would have to modify your queries because they don't all have the number of columns. Also, the SP_ should be avoided (or even better drop the prefix entirely). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0):

You can define the #table in the beginning and then use the

```
INSERT INTO
```

to add the values into it.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
( 
SomeFields VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO #tmp 
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Please check the tick button if you like the answer. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To insert data from Storec procedure into a table / temp table , first you need to create the table definition

Given below is the sample you can do.

```
create proc dbo.test
as
select 1 as b

create table #tmp(b int)

insert into #tmp exec dbo.test
```